# update manager keeps crashing but apt-get and aptitude is working

Tags: 12.10, apt, update-manager, software-updater

Since December last year i already got problems with the update manager it keeps crashing right from starting it, i already sended the crash report multiple times and searching the internet and this forum for fixes but nothing worked.

The apt-get and aptitude is working fine in the terminal.

Comment: We need to see what error you get or a link to the crash report that got created.

Comment: What website would you go to enter a crash report? (not everybody knows this)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this topic I was able to fix the problem I already have for months
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+question/213929

This is what I did:

Delete all the `*pyc` in:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/__pycache__
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-gi
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons this could happen. I spent several hours searching forums for an answer. The thing that worked for me is this:

Change the download source in System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Ubuntu Software.

Fixed it for me.